# Versatile Low Profile Video Card with Display Port, HDMI, DVI, and VGA

Tags: pcie, multiple-monitors, video-adapters

I'm looking for a low-profile PCI-Express video card that will support 1080p on at least 2 monitors simultaneously. That's easy to find, but I'm also wanting one that has the versatility of having all 4 of these ports:

1. Display Port
2. HDMI
3. DVI
4. VGA

It is easy to find inexpensive video cards that can do dual monitors at 1080p via all 3 of these ports: HDMI, DVI, and VGA. However, I can't find one that can do "all of those ports **plus Display Port**".

This is for a fleet of work computers. I just want to make sure that each one these computers has the flexibility to connect to what ever monitors are available at any given time I try to set them up (without using external adapters).

I need low profile because the video card will be installed in these bottom two slots (which are smaller than a full size PC slots):

[image]

Comment: @K7AAY : I don't have them in front of me to measure, but the general term for this size is "Low Profile". I've purchase ones in the past that use two slots to give HDMI, DVI, and VGA, but have never found one that can also do DisplayPort. They don't plug into two slots on the motherboard (only one), but it takes up two external slots bays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Gigabyte GV-N105TOC-4GL](https://gigabyte.com/us/Graphics-Card/GV-N105TOC-4GL/sp#sp) is only 37mm tall, it is specified as Low Profile, and includes

- DisplayPort 1.4
- DVI-D Dual-Link
- Two 2 HDMI 2.0 ports

You could add an [HDMI-VGA adapter](https://www.newegg.com/p/2VH-001M-00004?item=9SIA86V3E18207) for the VGA when needed, or perhaps you could use the motherboard video port of that [Dell Optiplex 780](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/servicetag/0-TzY0MWNWVlZZMERPZU96QkkzZW9vQT090/docs) for VGA monitors in parallel with the add-in card; Gigabyte could advise, and their US number is +1-626-854-9338.

Comment: That card almost addresses the versatility I'm looking for. It doesn't have VGA, but maybe I need to just go ahead and let VGA die. As you say, an adapter should be ok for VGA. So, one that supports only DisplayPort, HDMI, and DVI will be fine, but I'm use to getting the HDMI, DVI, VGA combo cards for around $40.00. It would be nice if I could find a DisplayPort, HDMI, DVI combo under $50.00. I'm only needing to support dual monitors at 1080p. Perhaps I'm asking too much when it comes to price.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [VGA is analog and the rest are digital](https://www.cnet.com/news/hdmi-vs-displayport-vs-dvi-vs-vga-which-connection-to-choose/). This limits somewhat your options because, in case of NVIDIA graphics cards, [the 900 series was the last one to support analog video through DVI-I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce#cite_ref-PCWorld_RIP_VGA_17-0). According to [this reply](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/1022700-most-powerful-dvi-i-gpu/?tab=comments#comment-12203919), there are some old AMD cards that also support it and you also might be able to convert between Display Port and VGA.

In other words, it is fairly easy to convert between digital connectors (DVI, HDMI) using a passive adapter. However, you need an active adapter to convert the signal between analog and digital, which are usually quite expensive.

As a result, [this is an example of a card that might suit you](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Gigabyte-Nvidia-DL-DVI-I-DVI-D-Graphics/dp/B01683DI74?th=1):

- on the top, it has a DVI-D slot (digital only).

On the bottom, it has (from left to right):

- a Display Port
- HDMI
- DVI-I slot (analog and digital), which means that you can use [a cheap adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000067SOH) (they are usually included in the graphics card box) and connect your VGA cable.

Apart from that, it looks like a low profile card (although "low profile" are usually considered the cards that occupy one slot and don't require external power), but I am not sure if it fits your case. You might want to take some measurements to be safe.

You might also have price and availability issues, as these card are a coupe generations old and you would probably only find them used. Since they are for a fleet of work computers as you say, the card than I linked above would probably be considered overkill.